# Replacing capitalized and non-capitalized string with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm working on a project where I have a string with content e.g. `$content`, and an array with words (with no capitals) e.g. `$rewrites`.

What I want to achieve, example case:

`$content` contains a string with the following text: 'Apples is the plural of apple, apples are delicious'.

`$rewrites` contains an array with the following data: 'apple', 'blueberry'.

Now I want to create a function that replaces all apple for something else, e.g. raspberry. But, in the string, there is Apples, which won't be replaced using `preg_replace`. Apples should be replaced with Raspberry (mention the capital R).

I tried different methods, and patterns but it won't work.

Currently I have the following code

```
foreach($rewrites as $rewrite){
      if(sp_match_string($rewrite->name, $content) && !in_array($rewrite->name, $spins) && $rewrite->name != $key){
        /* Replace the found parameter in the text */
        $content = str_replace($rewrite->name, $key, $content);

        /* Register the spin */
        $spins[] = $key;
      }
    }

function sp_match_string($needle, $haystack) {

 if (preg_match("/\b$needle\b/i", $haystack)) {
   return true;
 }
return false;

}
```

Comment: could you just add 'Apple', 'Blueberry' to your `$rewrites` array?

Comment: @BizzyBob No, it's not possible. Since if I add those to the array I cant know if I need to replace it with an capitalized word or not.

Comment: I'm saying search for uppercase and replace with uppercase. search for lowercase and replace with lowercase.

Comment: What about `apples`? Is the expected output `Raspberry is the plural of raspberry, apples are delicious`? Do you define the two arrays like `$rewrites = array('Apples', 'apple', 'blueberry');` and `$rewrites_repl = array('Raspberry', 'raspberry', 'gooseberry');`?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

I did it by building the various replacement cases on the fly.

```
$content = 'Apples is the plural of apple, apples are delicious';

$rewrites = array(
    array('apple', 'blueberry'),
    array('apple', 'raspberry')
);

echo "$content\n";
foreach ($rewrites as $rule) {
    $source = $rule[0];
    $target = $rule[1];

    // word and Word
    $find = array($source, ucfirst($source));
    $replace = array($target, ucfirst($target));

    // add plurals for source
    if (preg_match('/y$/', $source)) {
        $find[] = preg_replace('/y$/', 'ies', $source);
    } else {
        $find[] = $source . 's';
    }
    $find[] = ucfirst(end($find));

    // add plurals for target
    if (preg_match('/y$/', $target)) {
        $replace[] = preg_replace('/y$/', 'ies', $target);
    } else {
        $replace[] = $target . 's';
    }
    $replace[] = ucfirst(end($replace));

    // pad with regex
    foreach ($find as $i => $word) {
        $find[$i] = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
    }

    echo preg_replace($find, $replace, $content) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Apples is the plural of apple, apples are delicious
Blueberries is the plural of blueberry, blueberries are delicious
Raspberries is the plural of raspberry, raspberries are delicious
```